# How to annotate/map if no parent object declared in child class in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new bee in hibernate,and creating entities using annotations.Here i am using onetomany my xml looks like this

Answer.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.sample.Answer"
             table="ANSWERS">
             <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="answerId" type="java.lang.Long">
               <column name="ANSWER_ID"/>
              <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

          <property name="questionId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="QUESTION_ID"/>
             </property>

        <set name="answerText" table="ANSWERTEXT"
                inverse="true"  fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="ANSWER_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sample.AnswerText" />
        </set>
          </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

what i have tried: Annotated class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private Long  answerId;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    private Long      questionId;

    @OneToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();

    }
```

ANSWERTEXT class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERTEXT")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AnswerText {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT_ID")
    private Long answerTextId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private Long answerId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT")
    private String answerText;

    }
```

Here problem is there is no Answer(parent) object declaration in AnswerText(child) class.There they have declared only fileds.So how could i annotated properly in

```
private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();.
```

Please help me in this.Any help is appreciated.